# función naipes y arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Queremos escribir una función naipes, que dado un palo, devuelva una lista de strings, una por cada carta de ese palo según los naipes de la baraja española.

Tomar en cuenta que los naipes de la baraja española incluyen todas las numeradas del 1 al 12, pero para éste ejercicio no queremos incluir los 8 y los 9.

A la salida por ejemplo se debe obtener lo siguiente:

Naipes("espadas")
["1 de espadas", "2 de espadas", "3 de espadas" ..., "12 de espadas"], pero el arreglo no debe contener ni al 8 ni al 9

Tengo este código hecho pero me marca errores:

```js
function naipes(tipoPalo){
    let palo = tipoPalo;
    let nuevoArray = [];
    for (let i=1; i<=12; i++){
        if (tipoPalo==palo && i != 8 && i != 9);
        nuevoArray.push(i + " " + "de" + " " + tipoPalo);
    }
    return nuevoArray;
}

console.log(naipes('espadas'));
```

Comment: ¿Te marca errores o sencillamente no hace lo que quieres? Te recomiendo [edit] y comentar con más detalle el problema que tienes, así como completar el [tour] de bienvenida para conocer cómo se espera que plantees las preguntas y ganarte tu primera medalla. Bienvenido a SOes

Comment: Creo que te sobra el `;` al final de la linea del `if` (y para mayor claridad, poner la línea siguiente que sería el cuerpo del condicional, entre llaves)

Comment: Hola Chris, la sintaxis de tu if es incorrecta. Te faltan los ```{ }``` Deberia de see asi ```if ( condition )  { console.log( "hola mundo") }```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a que no incluye la respuesta a la condición dentro de las llaves {} en la línea 5 del código, sino que la corta antes.

```
function naipes(tipoPalo){
           let palo = tipoPalo;
           let nuevoArray = [];
           for (let i=1; i<=12; i++){
                if (i != 8 && i != 9){
                   nuevoArray.push(i + " " + "de" + " " + tipoPalo);
                }
           }
           return nuevoArray;
       }
         console.log(naipes('espadas'));
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes por favor considera añadir una explicación del código, sin una explicación nadie aprende nada. Revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)